# Activate a 5V relay with a 3V3 GPIO

Tags: mosfet

I need to activate a 5V relay with the 3V3 GPIO of an ESP8266.

However the GPIO pin to be used has an additional function as a boot mode select pin for which it must be high at startup, therefore the signal controlling the relay should be high when not activated, and low to activate it.

I was thinking about a P-Channel MOSFET acting as a switch, but any solution with minimum components is welcome.

Comment: The GPIO = 0 = relay on, complicates things. Most relays have 3 contacts per switch so you can just make GPIO = 1 = relay on, use an NMOS for that (simplest circuit) and then use the contacts of the relay that **open** when the relay is on. Also you need to search this site for "Arduino relay" to get some info on how this is done as similar questions to yours have been asked many times before.

Comment: In some cases GPIOs on 3.3V MCUs can tolerate 5 Volts. You want to specify your hardware more precisely.

Comment: Many of the off-the-shelf relay module PCBs are already set up so that it is a LOW input which activates the relay.  Specifically you drive the cathode of an optocoupler and visible LED in series.  Even though the anode voltage is 5v, the forward voltage drops of the two LEDs mean you can use a 3v3 output to drive the cathode input.

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't sound right that a GPIO (general purpose input/output) pin needs to be low to indicate the relay should be on.  Surely the microcontroller or FPGA driving the GPIO pin can invert the logic internally.

   Even if the digital signal is what it is, you can always invert it, then use simple circuits for driving a relay that have been posted many times here on this site.  This could be done with a additional transistor, or a explicit digital inverter.  Note that single inverters come in the same package that individual transistors come in.

   If you use the right part, read that datasheet, and do the math carefully, you should be able to drive a 5 V high side switch from a 3.3 V digital signal.  It's easy enough to turn on the high side switch with 0 V.  The tricky part is making sure it is off, or at least off enough, with 3.3 V in, while still ensuring sufficient current capability to power the relay at 0 V.

   A PNP with the right resistor divider driving the base should work.  But again, you have to design this carefully.

#1 is really the best choice.  Just invert the signal in the firmware or logic definition.

Comment: Olin Lathrop. Thanks for your response. Sometimes the simple solution are the best(#1). However in my case, on an esp8266 GPIO0 and GPIO2 must be high to boot from flash SPI. I could used another GPIO you would say.... Yes you are also right about that but again If there is a way to utilized these two bootstrapping inputs for something useful I would prefer it. So if you have a nice solution( few components as possible) I am all ears:-)

Comment: @qnxSmith - Olin's option 2 is pretty good: use a standard n channel MOSFET to drive the relay (or an npn bjt). Run that off an inverter (which could be a transistor and a resistor, or you could use a logic ic, eg a [74HC1G04](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT1G04.pdf) ), and use a pull-up resistor to ensure the GPIO is high until the microcontroller starts driving it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. As I understand, you need to use a dual-function pin, and separate a bootstrap function from driving a relay, and you want to avoid the relay's premature engagement or glitching during power-on.

I am afraid there is no simple solution if you want your system to operate 100% reliably, because the boot function involves some power-up sequencing, time to de-assert hardware reset (external or internal POR, whatever), boot the code, etc. All this will depend on how fast your external power is ramping up, which might be difficult to specify under all conditions.

Therefore the solution must include a delay, the relay section (or its control) must be totally disabled during boot process. Normally the enabling of power side of electronics is done by a different GPIO with guaranteed initial state, but since you don't have one, you must use some type of RC delay of sufficient length to keep the relay control disabled until the system boots and sets the dual-function pin into desired logic state.

I would suggest to look into "[configurable tiny/little logic](http://www.ti.com/pdfs/logic/lvc1g97-98a.pdf)" like LVC1G57/58 or LVC1G97/98, and use one of inputs with a long RC as a delayed "enable", the circuits have nice feature of having Schmitt triggers on all inputs. And then use the standard N-FET transistor to drive the relay coil.